# How to use argparse without using dest variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I want to use `argparse` to get option to my program. Here is my sample program:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()

print("enter the numbers:")

a=int(input("number 1:"))

b=int(input("number 2:"))

parser.add_argument('-a','--add')

parser.add_argument('-s','--sub')

options = parser.parse_args()

if options:

        c=a+b

if options.d:

        c=a-b

print(c)
```

it gives the output correctly if I use

```
python file.pu -a 1
```

But I don't want to give value like `1` in compilation. What I want is

```
python file.py -a
```

that performs addition.

```
python file.py -s
```

that performs subtraction.

How to change the code for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
action='store_true'
```

...in the following:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '-add', action='store_true')
```